# A proof for a Hardy inequality for holomorphic functions in Hardy space $H^1$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, fourier-analysis, hardy-spaces

Let $H^1$ be the [Hardy space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy_space#Hardy_spaces_for_the_unit_disk) of holomorphic functions on the unit disk.

Where can I find a proof (as simple and selfcontained as possible) of this result?

If $f\in H^1$, then

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\hat{f}(n)}{n+1}\leq C \|f\|_1$$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio The Hardy spaces tag suggests we are talking about $H^1$ being a Hardy space of holomorphic function on the unit disk. Hence the Fourier coefficients being from $0$ to $\infty$ only (really, they are the coefficients of the power series centered at $0$.)

Comment: @SFTP: many thanks for the clarification, I am used to read $H^1$ as the space of functions such that $f,\nabla f \in L^2(\mathbb{R^n})$. So, given $$ f(x) = \sum_{n\geq 0} c_n x^n, $$ the OP is asking for a proof of $$\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx \leq C\| f\|_1\stackrel{?}{=}C\oint_{|z|=1}|f(z)|\,dz$$ ?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Yes, that; except one can't always integrate over the unit circle, so the Hardy norm is $\sup_{0<r<1}\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{|z|=r} |f(z)||dz|$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Duren's book *Theory of $H^p$ spaces* has a stronger result as a Corollary on page 48.

> If $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n \in H^1$, then 
>   $$
> \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{|a_n|}{n+1} \le \pi \|f\|_1
> $$
>   where 
>   $$
> \|f\|_1 = \frac{1}{2\pi}\sup_{0<r<1}\int_0^{2\pi}|f(re^{it})|\,dt
> $$

Proof: for $t\in [0, 2\pi)$ define 
$\psi(t) = ie^{-it} (\pi-t)$. Then $\|\psi\|_\infty = \pi$ and the Fourier coefficients are
$$
\widehat{\psi}(n) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} e^{-int} \psi(t)\,dt = \frac{1}{n+1}
$$
Given $f\in H^1$, factor it as $f=B\varphi $ where $B$ is a Blaschke product and $\varphi$ has no zeros in the unit disk. Let $g=B\sqrt{\varphi}$ and $h=\sqrt{\varphi}$, so that $f=gh$. Writing $g(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n z^n$ and $h(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n z^n  $ we get 
$$
a_n = \sum_{k=0}^n b_k c_{n-k}
$$
By the triangle inequality,
$$
\sum_{n=0}^N \frac{|a_n|}{n+1} = \sum_{n=0}^N \widehat{\psi}(n)|a_n|
\le \sum_{k, m = 0 }^N \widehat{\psi}(k+m)|b_k||c_m|
$$
Let $A(b, c)$ denote the right hand side. The key fact is that 
$$
|A(x, y)| \le \|\psi\|_\infty \|x\|_2 \|y\|_2 \tag1
$$
for any vectors $x, y$, where the vector norms are Euclidean. Once (1) is proved, the result follows because by Parseval, $\|b\|_2 \|c\|_2 = \|g\|_2\|h\|_2 = \|f\|_1$.

---

Proof of (1) begins by introducing, for any coefficients $x_n$, the function $P(t) = \sum_{n=0}^N x_n e^{-int}$. Note that $P(t)^2$ is a double sum of terms like $x_nx_me^{-i(n+m)t}$. Integrating this against $\psi$ shows that 
$$
|A(x,x)| =  \frac{1}{2\pi} \left|\int_0^{2\pi} P(t)^2 \psi(t)\,dt\right|
\le \|\psi\|_\infty \|x\|_2
$$
which gives a special case of (1). The general case follows by polarization:
$$
A(x, y) = \frac14(A(x+y,x+y) - A(x-y, x-y))
$$ 
hence
$$
|A(x, y)| \le \frac14\|\psi\|_\infty(\|x+y\|^2 + \|x-y\|^2)
= \frac12\|\psi\|_\infty(\|x\|^2 + \|y\|^2)
$$ 
The final step is to notice we can multiply $x$ by one scalar while dividing $y$ by the same scalar, thus reducing the problem to $\|x\|=\|y\|$, in which case 
$$
\frac12\|\psi\|_\infty(\|x\|^2 + \|y\|^2) = \|\psi\|_\infty \|x\|  \|y\|
$$

Comment: Fantastic explanation! Out of curiosity, is it known if the constant $\pi$ is the best possible?