# Taylor Series of $e^{is\sqrt{x+1}}$ and Bell Polynomials

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, taylor-expansion, generating-functions, function-and-relation-composition

I'm interested in finding the Taylor expansion of $e^{is\sqrt{x+1}}$ with $x, s \in \mathbb{R}$, say for a branch cut at $x = 0$. More specifically I'm interested in putting a bound on the sum of the 1-norm of the coefficients. That is, if I have:

$$e^{is\sqrt{x+1}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$$

How can I bound $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \vert a_n\vert$ or even $\sum_{n=0}^M \vert a_n\vert$? From what I've gathered, each $a_n$ is determined using Bell's polynomials, but I'm really not sure how to deal with the Bell Polynomials.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I would also be interested in being able to do the above in general for $e^{isf(x)}$.

Comment: This function of $x$ has a branch point at $x=0$; the series is like this:
$$
e^{is\sqrt{x}} = 1 + is\sqrt{x} - \frac{s^2x}{2} -\frac{i s^3 x^{3/2}}{6} +\dots
$$
it is a power series in $\sqrt{x}$.  I do not understand the thing about Bell polynomials.

Comment: @GEdgar I'm looking for the series representation where we have a power series in $x$ which is essentially when you sub-in the Taylor series of $is\sqrt{x}$ into the Taylor series of $e^x$ and expand the powers of an infinite sum. That's where [Bell Polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials#Properties) come in. I need this specific representation because I want to invoke another theorem.

Comment: I am not sure what you want but any expansion $e^{is\sqrt{x}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ convergent on a small disc around zero, would give an analytic extension there to $e^{is\sqrt{x}}$ which simply doesn't exist; $\sqrt x$ has no expansion at $0$ (even as a real function it is not differentiable at $0$ on $[0,1]$ say) so not sure what you were talking about substituting etc

Comment: I'm looking for an expression where $x$ is a real number. You're right about it not being differentiable at 0. So let's say we replaced $\sqrt{x}$ with $\sqrt{x+1}$

Comment: this is completely different question which indeed makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure that this is what you want but one can use [Hardy inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2732274/a-proof-for-a-hardy-inequality-for-holomorphic-functions-in-hardy-space-h1) which says that if $g(z)=\sum_{n \ge 0} b_nz^n \in H^1$  then $\sum_{ n \ge 0}\frac {|b_n|}{n+1} \le \pi ||g||_1$

(where as usual $||g||_1=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|g(e^{i\theta})|d\theta$, where by a slight abuse of notation we denote by $g(e^{i\theta})$ the radial limit of $g$ which exists ae and is integrable on the unit circle by the assumption $g \in H^1$)

Taking $f(z)=e^{is\sqrt{z+1}}, g(z)=f'(z)=\frac{is}{2\sqrt {z+1}}e^{is\sqrt{z+1}}$ (where $f(0)=e^{is}$ to fix the principal square root branch in the unit disc) we notice that $g(z)=\frac{c(z)}{\sqrt {z+1}}$ with $c(z)$ continuous in the closed unit disc (since $\sqrt {1+z}$ is so and actually has an absolutely convergent Taylor series in the closed unit disc by easy estimates)  hence $\frac{c(z)}{\sqrt {z+1}} \in H^{2-\epsilon}$  so [in particular in $H^1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy_space)

Applying Hardy inequality to $g$ we get that if $f(z)=e^{is\sqrt{z+1}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$, so for $g(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n z^n, a_{n+1}=\frac{b_n}{n+1}, n \ge 0$ we have that

$$\sum_{n \ge 1} |a_n|  \le \pi ||g||_1$$ so $$\sum_{n \ge 0} |a_n| \le e^{-\Im s}+\pi ||g||_1$$

Now on the unit circle $z=e^{i\theta},1+z=2\cos \frac{\theta}{2}e^{i\theta/2}, \theta \in [-\pi, \pi]$ hence $ \sqrt {1+z}=\sqrt {2\cos \frac{\theta}{2}} e^{i\theta/4}$ by our principal branch choice for which  $\sqrt {z+1}=2, z=1$ so one can find the maximum $c(s)$ of $|e^{is\sqrt{z+1}}|$ in terms of $\arg s$ so one can majorize $||g||_1$ by using $||g||_1=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|g(e^{i\theta})|d\theta \le \frac{|s|c(s)}{2}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt {2\cos \frac{\theta}{2}}}< 2|s|c(s)/\pi$ since the integral in $\theta$ is $7.41..$ (has actually [a closed expression](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=integrate%20%5B%281%2F%282%20Cos%5Bt%2F2%5D%29%5E1%2F2%29%2C%20t%2C%20-Pi%2C%20Pi%5D) using $\Gamma$ function )

For example, if $s$ is real one has $\Re (is \sqrt {z+1})=-\sqrt {2\cos \frac{\theta}{2}}s\sin \theta/4$ and by symmetry, we can take $s$ negative so majorize $\sqrt {2\cos \frac{\theta}{2}}\sin \theta/4, 0 \le \theta \le \pi$ and find $c(s)=e^{c|s|}$ where $c$ is the maximum above, while if $s=ia, a \in \mathbb R$ one easily sees that $c(s)=1$ if $a>0$ and $c(s)=e^{|a|\sqrt 2}$ if $a<0$ so the final result will definitely depend on the argument of $s$

If one needs, one can definitely analyze $||g||_1$ more carefully but I suspect that the general form of the bound $K|s|e^{h(|s|,\arg s)}$ is the best one can get from this approach

Edit later based on the condition that $s$ is real; as noted above in this case the crude bound one gets is $2|s|e^{c|s|}$ where $c$ is the maximum of  $\sqrt {2\cos \frac{\theta}{2}}\sin \theta/4, 0 \le \theta \le \pi$; a quick computation gets us that $c=1/2, \theta=2\pi/3$ so the crude bound is $2|s|e^{|s|/2}$. Now the exponential part can not be changed since the integrand will be close to this on a large enough arc near $\pm 2\pi/3$, but for large $|s|$ one probably can reduce the power of $s$ by a more careful estimate of the original integral.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. I had a few questions. Before that, let me clarify that I'm interested in the expansion of $e^{is\sqrt{x+1}}$ for $x, s\in\mathbb{R}$. I guess this would fall in the category of $\|g\| < 2\vert s\vert c(s)/\pi$, and $c(s) = e^{c\vert s\vert}$. What's c here? You say "where c is the maximum above", but I'm not sure what you're referring to. Also, could you clarify what $K$ and $h$ are in $K|s|e^{h(|s|,\arg s)}$?

Comment: $K$ is just a constant (in the fairly coarse approximation above is $2/\pi$); for real $s$ one has as bounds just $K|s|e^{c|s|}$ where $c$ is the maximum of the theta expression above

Comment: I see, thank you! Just a few more clarifications since I'll be doing a formal proof for this. What's $H^1$? What's $H^{1/2 + \epsilon}$? Can I invoke this technique for functions other than $\sqrt{1+x}$ and if so what condition do they need to satisfy? Lastly, do you have any references for Hardy inequality that you used? because when I look at the Wikipedia page for it, I don't see it in the form written here. Thank you!

Comment: $H^p$ are the Hrdy spaces - so holomorphic functions on the unit disc with some boundary conditions (at least for $H^p, p \ge 1$ the best way to think of them is that they have radial limits ae which are in $L^p$ and which satisfy that $\hat {f}(n)=0, n >0$ for their Fourier coefficients so if $f(z)=\sum a_nz^n, f(e^{i\theta})=\sum a_ne^{in\theta}$ ae; for example $(1+z)^{-\delta}$ is in the Hardy space $H^p$ precisely when $p \delta <1$ so $1/y^{p\delta}$ is integrable at zero; so for $\delta =1/2$ this means $p=2-\epsilon$ (the $1/2+\epsilon$ was a typo and fixed it)

Comment: Added links to a proof of Hardy inequality in this context here on MSE and to the basic Wikipedia article on the Hardy spaces; the same proof works for $f(x)$ when it is the restriction of an a analytic function on the unit disc for which $f' \in H^1$; for example any $f(x)=(x+1)^{\delta}, 0 < \delta <1$ works since $f'$ is integrable at $-1$ so is in $H^1$ while obviously $e^{isf}$ is continuous on the closed unit circle as before so $(e^{isf})' \in H^1$; any such $f$ has absolutely convergent series on the closed unit disc by the Hardy inequality;

Comment: Any idea how I could approach the problem if I wanted to get a bound on the 1-norm of the truncated expansion such that $|e^{is\sqrt{x+1}} - \sum_{k=0}^K a_k x^k|\leq \epsilon$ for $x\in [-1+\delta, 1-\delta]$?

Comment: I would find a bound on $|a_k|, k \ge K$ (could be a function of $K$ that goes to zero or just a coarse bound given by $||e^{is\sqrt{x+1}}||_p, p=1,2$ on the unit circle and then majorize $|\sum_{k \ge K} a_k x^k|$ by the geometric series; depends on how fine you want your final result

Comment: Hey, so I just posted a [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4583846/fourier-approximation-of-eis-sqrtx) about this, trying a different approach to approximate the function using Fourier series instead of Taylor series. You seem to know a lot about this stuff, I would appreciate any insight you might have.

Comment: I know it's been a while since I posted this question, but I was wondering if the same proof would apply if instead of $e^{is\sqrt{x+1}}$ we had $e^{is\sqrt{x+0.5}}$? Would $g$ still be in $\mathcal{H}^1$?

Comment: here the derivative has a singularity at $-1/2$ so probably you need to change variables $z \to 2z$ as the coefficients are now on the order of $2^n$

Answer (score 1):

**Remark.**  It seems the series the OP wants is this one ...
$$
{\rm e}^{i s \sqrt{x+1}} =
{{\rm e}^{is}}+{\frac {i}{2}}{{\rm e}^{is}}sx+{{\rm e}^{is}} \left( -
{\frac {i}{8}}s-{\frac {{s}^{2}}{8}} \right) {x}^{2}+{{\rm e}^{is}}
 \left( {\frac {i}{16}}s+{\frac {{s}^{2}}{16}}-{\frac {i}{48}}{s}^{3}
 \right) {x}^{3}
\\
+{{\rm e}^{is}} \left( -{\frac {5\,i}{128}}s-{\frac {5
\,{s}^{2}}{128}}+{\frac {i}{64}}{s}^{3}+{\frac {{s}^{4}}{384}}
 \right) {x}^{4}
\\
+{{\rm e}^{is}} \left( {\frac {7\,i}{256}}s+{\frac {7
\,{s}^{2}}{256}}-{\frac {3\,i}{256}}{s}^{3}-{\frac {{s}^{4}}{384}}+{
\frac {i}{3840}}{s}^{5} \right) {x}^{5}+\dots
$$

Comment: Yes! That's the type of series I'm looking for and indeed that's what I get when I use WolframAlpha but in order to get the bound I'm looking for I need an explicit formula for it